# How to floor a number using the NTL library (C++)

Tags: c++, math, floor, ntl

I am building a C++ program to verify a mathematical conjecture for up to 100 billion iterations.  In order to test such high numbers, I cannot use a `C++ int`, so I am using the `NTL` library, using the type `ZZ` as my number type.

My algorithm looks like this:

```
ZZ generateNthSeq(ZZ n)
{
    return floor(n*sqrt(2));
}
```

I have the two libraries being imported:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <NTL/ZZ.h>
```

But obviously this cannot compile because I get the error:

```
$ g++ deepness*.cpp
deepness.cpp: In function ‘NTL::ZZ generateNthSeq(NTL::ZZ)’:
deepness.cpp:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘floor(NTL::ZZ)’
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:185: note: candidates are: double floor(double)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:262: note:                 long double std::floor(long double)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cmath:258: note:                 float std::floor(float)
```

Stating that the floor mathematical operation cannot accept a ZZ class type.  But I need the numbers to be pretty big.  How can I accomplish what I want to do, which is to floor the function, while using the NTL library?

Comment: Looks like n * squrt(2) is returning a double instead of an NTL::ZZ
Maybe your library has its own squrt function?

Comment: I don't know the library, but if it is the one described at http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex1.html apparently it has "`SqrRoot`  -- integer part of square root". So you could try something like `SqrRoot(2*n*n)`, assuming n is positive (and `-SqrRoot(2*n*n)` otherwise).

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have changed my algorithm to have `floor(SqrRoot(2*n*n))`. The `SqrRoot` now returns a ZZ, but still there is not `floor` function in the NTL library or C++ libraries that accepts a `ZZ`, which is the real problem listed above.  There is no matching call for a `floor:(NTL::ZZ)`.  Need more help.

Comment: Why do you need to apply floor? According to what I quoted, SqrRoot already returns the _integer part_ of the square root.

Comment: .. specifically, the header comments `x = floor(a^{1/2}) (a >= 0)`

Comment: Sorry @CompuChip, I missed where you talked about the integer part of the square root.  I looked that up and you are correct.  I'm applying those changes right now.  Thanks - I'll report if it worked or not.

Comment: @CompuChip your answer was most helpful.  I was able to get those changes in, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for looking that up for me.  Wish I could give you more points then just an upped comment.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it doesn't really make sense to apply `floor` to an integral type (well, it does, it's just a no-op). What you should be really worried about is the fact that your code is apparently passing something of type `ZZ` into `floor`!

That is, what can `n * sqrt(2)` possibly mean here?

Also, before even writing that, I'd've checked the documentation to see if integer * floating point actually exists in the library -- usually for that to be useful at all, you need arbitrary precision floating types available.

---

Checking through the headers, there is only one multiplication operator:

```
ZZ operator*(const ZZ& a, const ZZ& b);
```

and there is a conversion constructor:

```
explicit ZZ(long a);  // promotion constructor
```

I can't figure out how your code is even compiling. Maybe you're using a different version of the library than I'm looking at, and the conversion constructor is implicit, and your `double` is getting "promoted" to a `ZZ`. This is surely not what you want, since promoting `sqrt(2)` to a `ZZ` is simply going to give you the integer `1`.

You either need to:

- look into whether or not NTL has arbitrary precision floating point capabilities
- switch to a library that does have arbitrary precision floating point capabilities
- convert your calculation to pure integer arithmetic

That last one is fairly easy here: you want

```
return SqrRoot(sqr(n) * 2); // sqr(n) will be a bit more efficient than `n * n`
```

Comment: Incidentally, even if you had arbitrary precision floating point available, the pure integer version is still probably the better way to do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks @Hurkyl for all your information.  The thing I really needed was just the last bit you mentioned.  This is for a class, and there are requirements for libraries to be used and how to set this up, so I was under the constraints I mentioned above.  What I really needed to know was the SqrRoot() NTL function returned an rounded off int, which was what I needed.